# Rename column values using pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

in one of the columns in my dataframe I have five values:

```
1,G,2,3,4
```

How to make it change the name of all "G" to 1

I tried:

```
df = df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1})
```

I also tried:

```
df = df['col_name'].replace('G',1)
```

"G" is in fact 1 (I do not know why there is a mixed naming)

Edit:

works correctly with:

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1})
```

Comment: Won't you have duplicate column names? Do you want that?

Comment: `df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1})` is the right (a right) thing to do.  You just need to assign it back to the dataframe appropriately.  `df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1})` **OR** `df.update(df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1}))` **OR** `df = df.assign(col_name=df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1}))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you are trying to change the values in a column and not the column name itself.

Given you have mixed data type there, I assume that column is of type `object` and thus the number is read as string.

```
df['col_name'] = df['col_name'].str.replace('G', '1')
```

Comment: There is no reason why OP's approach of `df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1})` won't work. Nothing magical about `df['col_name'].str.replace('G', '1'))` is any better.  It's the assignment back to the dataframe that is messed up.

Comment: I dont think this would solve the issue. I manually checked and df['col_name'].replace({'G': 1}) is working fine too.

Answer (score 4):

You could try the following line

```
df.replace('G', 1, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

use numpy

```
import numpy as np

df['a'] = np.where((df.a =='G'), 1, df.a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, lets say your data is like :

```
ab=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,'G',5]})
```

And you will replace it as :

```
ab1=ab.replace('G',4)
```